# proper way to get nice string from exception

Tags: python, exception, python-3.x, formatting

I want to generate a one-line string from an `Exception` which tells me **what** happened **where** (don't need a full backtrace). The following information would be nice:

- filename / linenumber
- exception type
- exception description (what you get from `str(e)`)
- nice to have: function/method/class

Currently I do the following:

```
import os
...
try:
    os.nonexisting()
except Exception as e:
    t = e.__traceback__
    tbf = e.__traceback__.tb_frame
    print('%s:%d: %s in %s(): "%s" ' %
        os.path.basename(tbf.f_code.co_filename),
        t.tb_lineno,
        e.__class__.__name__,
        tbf.f_code.co_name, e))
```

which gives me:

```
foo.py:203: AttributeError in foo(): "'module' object has no attribute 'nonexisting'"
```

Is there a more elegant way to print out the details given in this example? I'm thinking about s.th. like

```
print(e.format('%f: %l: %t %F: "%w"'))
```

I'd like to avoid importing extra modules except there is one exactly for this purpose.

Answer (score 4):

I think [`traceback.format_exception_only`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.format_exception_only) does exactly what you want.

```
try:
    os.nonexisting()
except Exception as e:
    print(traceback.format_exception_only(e.__class__, e))
```

Comment: It produces `["AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'nonexisting'\n"]` that is not what OP wants (where is filename, line number, function/method name?).

Comment: Indeed the problem is to add file / line number information to `format_exception()` without fiddling with the internals of `sys.exc_info()`, `extract_tb`, etc.