# Display stacktrace while running python file

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my current project, I am executing a block of python code from bash. This is a multi-layer architecture, once a mouse click is made on the UI, I invoke a command inside a terminal to run a python based dash-server, which then generates a preview of the code.

The command I am executing is ,`HOST=0.0.0.0 PORT=8050 python -m utils` this starts up a dash server.

```
Dash is running on http://0.0.0.0:8050/proxy/8050/

 * Serving Flask app 'utils'
 * Debug mode: on
```

Sometimes, the utils.py throws an error. The code it's trying to run is written dynamically and input by a user. The objective is to catch this python error stacktrace (if any) and display it inside the UI.

Does anyone know how to catch/detect the stacktrace generated from running python command inside a Bash Terminal?

Comment: Use the [`traceback`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html) module. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30728008/proper-way-to-get-nice-string-from-exception for example.